# Database design - should all image-related data (notwithstanding the image file itself) be stored within a single table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-design

I'm wondering whether it makes sense to store data for all of my application's user-uploaded images within the same table--e.g., an "images" table.

I've contemplated creating multiple tables--e.g., "usersImages", "productImages", etc.--but vaguely recall reading something about giving a non-join table a name containing two nouns as being symptomatic of poor database structure, the problem basically being that a name like "productImages" describes two discrete entities, each requiring its own table and a join table should the need to associate the two arise. So, that said, would an "images" table containing data for ALL images be a good idea?

Comment: I'd go with polymorphic associations. One table for images and filter by type, like `ProducImage`, `UserImage` etc..

Comment: Could you say more? Also, is your presumption that an image can have only one type? (That's probably a safe presumption, but I have to ask.)

Comment: What does filtering by type look like in code? I've not done this before.

Comment: In case of product with id 4 `@product.images` it will be something like .. `select images from images where images.imageable_type = 'Product' and images.imageable_id = 4`

Comment: go with `polymorphic associations` and you'll thank me later. I did it your way saving alike models in different tables and I regretted it later. Better take a little time to understand it so you don't waste a lot of time to fix it.

Comment: This . . . "select images from images where images.imageable_type". Where would that code go? That looks like a custom database query. Would I write that within my model? My controller? Sorry--I know this is a total newbie question. There's a lot I understand about Rails, but some things are still foreign to me.

Comment: That was just a piece of sql query to show how it would look when in code you'll write `@product.images`. You don't need to put that anywhere. Read the link attached in the answer, you'll get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

exactly your case

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, as: :imageable
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, as: :imageable
end
```